# Разбить строку по нескольким условиям (Python)

Tags: python, split

У меня есть датафрейм с большим количеством адресов. Адреса идут одной строкой и не соответствуют одной маске. Необходимо получить название улицы.
Встречается три варианта написания адресов:

```
Вспольный переулок, дом 19/20, строение 1
город Москва, 104-й километр Московской Кольцевой Автодороги, дом 6
город Москва, город Зеленоград, Георгиевский проспект, дом 5
```

Я написал такой код. Он вроде бы работает, но очень медленно - на мощном сервере перебирает 20к строк более 15 минут. Подскажите, как можно оптимизировать.

```
for i in df['address']:
    if ('Зеленоград' in i) or ('Троицк' in i) or ('Щербинка' in i):
        df['street'] = df['address'].str.split(',', expand=True)[2]
    elif 'город Москва' not in i:
        df['street'] = df['address'].str.split(',', expand=True)[0]
    else:
        df['street'] = df['address'].str.split(',', expand=True)[1]
```

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что все варианты названия улиц идут непосредственно перед словосочетанием ", дом"?

Comment: Нет, бывают и другие написания - "город Москва, Варшавское шоссе, владение 129Г",  "город Москва, город Зеленоград, корпус 1138"

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеку [natasha](https://github.com/natasha/natasha), а конкретно пример с [AddrExtractor](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/natasha/natasha/blob/master/docs.ipynb#AddrExtractor). На ваших примерах 104 километр не разбирается нормально, остальное более-менее разбирает успешно: https://gist.github.com/insolor/1512ac7a46636f32409d1635bd82b7bc